# Is there any reason to not run the scheduled job Clean-up Temporary Data and Files every hour?

Tags: smartgroups, settings, scheduled-job, cache

I discovered some problems with Smart Groups that use IN search criteria for custom fields not showing counts. I have the scheduled job Rebuild Smart Group Cache running. However, only after running Administer -> System Settings -> Cleanup Caches and Update Paths, then selecting Update Smart Group Counts, was I able to see updated Smart Group counts.

It seems running the scheduled job Clean-up Temporary Data and Files *should* do the same thing as Cleanup Caches, since it "[r]emoves temporary data and files, and clears old data from cache tables". Is that the case?

Currently the scheduled job Cleanup Caches and Update Paths is disabled.

So - is there any reason to *not* run the scheduled job Clean-up Temporary Data and Files every hour?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I have mine set to run every hour and have for quite some time now and have seen no issues with it.

Comment: @frTommy thanks, I've had it running hourly now since last night, no issues have occured that I see, scheduled job log is reporting Success for each occurrence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check how long it takes to run on your system. if it doesn't take too long, I don't see any reason not to run it hourly.